# Book about King Arthur. Written as a framed story by an old man in a monastery who was a boy while it happened. Lancelot was the worst

Tags: story-identification

I am looking for a book I read in high school (for high school), probably in 2011 or 2012, which was a loose retelling of part of the story of King Arthur. The main character was a young man during the events and was telling the story to a priest or monk in a monastery now that he was old. The main character was not King Arthur or one of the knights and was significantly lower status than them.

One distinctive feature of the book was that Lancelot was a horrible and contemptible person. He did literally nothing of value but paid a whole bunch of bards to tell amazing stories about him so everyone thought he was incredible. The main character hated him, and I believe the hatred was returned.

There was also a spooky island where all the crazy people in the surrounding kingdoms get sent, and the main character somehow ends up trapped there. He survives for a while on this insane asylum island, and when he finds a way back suddenly everyone respects him more because the superstitions build the island up to be basically hell and he managed to return.

At some point the main character sees Merlin intervene in a battle where he basically negotiates with one of King Arthur's enemies and convinces them to ally with King Arthur instead halfway through the battle, which turns the tide. It seems implied that Merlin has no (or very minor) magic and the main thing he has going for him is enough respect that everyone, even enemies, are willing to negotiate with him and take his word seriously.

For further details it was a pretty long book. I think in the monastery the person he was telling the story to might have been getting the story on behalf of the current queen. It felt a lot closer to an alternate history than a full fantasy story.

Comment: Lancelot being something of an antagonist is seen in many versions of the King Arthur legend.  For example, one repeated element in Arthurian legend is that Lancelot is often seen to be having a secret affair with Lady Gwynevere.

Answer (score 26):

This sounds like the [Warlord trilogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Warlord_Chronicles) by Bernard Cornwell.

It is narrated by *Derfel Cadarn* and it opens with him as an old man in a monastery. During the book he becomes a great warrior and witnesses the events of Arthur's reign first hand.

Derfel says of Lancelot;

> Two years we fought. Two years against all odds. Two years of splendour and vileness. Two years of slaughter and feast, of broken swords and shattered shields, of victory and disaster, and in all those
> months and in all those sweated fights when brave men choked on their own life blood and ordinary men did deeds they never dreamed possible, I never saw Lancelot once. Yet the poets said he was the hero
> of Benoic, the most perfect warrior, the fighter of fighters. The poets said that preserving Benoic was Lancelot's fight, not mine, not Galahad's, not Culhwch's, but Lancelot's. But Lancelot spent the war in
> bed, begging his mother to bring him wine and honey.
>
> No, not always in bed. Lancelot was sometimes at a fight, but always a mile behind so that he could be first back to Ynys Trebes with his news of victory. He knew how to tear a cloak, batter a sword edge, rumple his oiled hair and even cut his face so that he staggered home looking the hero, and then his mother would have the fili compose a new song and the song would be carried to Britain by traders and seamen so that even in distant Rheged, north of Elmet, they believed that Lancelot was the new Arthur.

The island is the *Isle of the Dead* and it's where dangerous lunatics are kept. For example Derfel says of *Pellinore*:

> Pellinore gave me that ambition. Pellinore was the favourite of all Merlin's creatures. He was a king, but the Saxons had taken his land and his eyes, and the Gods had taken his mind. He should have been sent
> to the Isle of the Dead, where the dangerous mad went, but Merlin  ordered him kept on the Tor locked in a small compound like the one where Druidan kept his pigs.

The battle in which Merlin intervenes is when *Gorfyddyd* attacks Arthur. He persuades the *Blackshield Irish* to change sides:

> Merlin turned to Sagramor and me. "The Blackshield Irish," he said in a casual voice, 'are on your side. I talked with them. They will attack Gorfyddyd's men and you shall have a great victory. May the Gods give you strength." He turned again, put an arm around Nimue's shoulders and strode away through the enemy ranks that opened to let him through.

Comment: Adding to this, the OP said "It seems implied that Merlin has no (or very minor) magic" and "It felt a lot closer to an alternate history than a full fantasy story." The Warlord trilogy was intentionally written as a plausible pseudo-historical retelling of the Arthur myth, so magic was left as largely a bunch of tricks, coincidences, and good PR. It's supposed to read like alternate history, not fantasy, of the Arthurian characters in an historically accurate setting (post-Roman Britain as the Saxons were displacing the Britons).

Comment: "Magic was left as largely a bunch of tricks, coincidences, and good PR" -- largely, but not entirely: there are a few crucial points in the books where Merlin's spells seem to achieve effects with no plausible non-magical explanation (e.g. the Northern Lights suddenly appearing in the sky, far outside their normal geographical range, when Merlin performs a ritual to summon the Celtic gods).

Comment: @DavidLoeffler: Yeah, they leave some room for "maybe he did magic" in a few cases. That said, the northern lights *do* come that far south in the real world (after solar storms); it's always possible he just has some unusual levels of "secret druid knowledge" that allows him to predict them (yes, I know there's no science of the time that could predict powerful auroras), or that he basically does things with enough confidence and showmanship that, when it happens to go well, people credit him for it, and when it doesn't, they're willing to see smaller successes in just about any coincidence.

Comment: The main character is deep on the inside with Merlin and (especially) Nimue early on, and you're *shown* how much of it is basically tricks, it's just left unclear whether some of it (especially bits seen after the main character is on the outs with them) might be real.